# Refresh Skrollr on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, skrollr

I'm using constants which are based on my window height - so if a user resized their browser the height could change. I'd obviously like to recalculate the browser height when the window is resized. This is what I currently have but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
function resize_articles() {
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height() - 80;                            

    var constantsData = Math.floor(viewportHeight * 1); 
    var s = skrollr.init({
        //smoothScroll: false,
        forceHeight: false,
        constants: {
        foobar: constantsData
        }
    });
    /* Initialise skrollr scroll menu */
    skrollr.menu.init(s, {
        animate: true
    });

    /* Building links */
    $('#link1').attr('data-menu-top', (viewportHeight + 400)); 
    $('#link2').attr('data-menu-top', (viewportHeight + 900));
    $('#link3').attr('data-menu-top', (viewportHeight + 1500));

    s.refresh();
}
resize_articles();

$(window).resize(function() {   
    resize_articles();
    //skrollr.get().refresh(document.getElementsByClassName('skrollr'));
});
```

I've tried to call the resize_articles function on page resize and another snippet I found while looking around - but neither seem to work correctly. Have I set it up wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `init` multiple times is a noop. Also you don't need to initialize skrollr-menu again, it will just work with the updates links.

With the latest skrollr you can just do this

```
var s = skrollr.init({
    //smoothScroll: false,
    forceHeight: false,
    constants: {
        foobar: function() {
            return $(window).height() - 80;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly. I'm not sure what you meant by calling init multiple times as I tried removing the skrollr.menu and the links stopped working.

Comment: You're executing `resize_articles` more than once. But neither skrollr nor skrollr-menu expect to be initialized **more** than once.

Comment: I thought by declaring resize_articles as function I then had to start it by resize_articles()? And then I thought it had to be declared again in the resize function. Is that incorrect (I'm still learning jQuery so excuse the ignorance!)?

Comment: What you say is absolutely correct. **But** inside of that function you are initializing skrollr. And then when a resize event occurs the function is executed again and skrollr is initialized **a second time**.